# C sscanf not working correctly with char pointer

Tags: c, scanf, c-strings, chess

I'm trying to parse a [FEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) using sscanf in C. I have the following code:

```c
int main() {
  char side, pos[128], castle[4], enpas[2];
  int halfMove, fullMove;
  const char fen[] = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
  const int res = sscanf(fen, "%s %c %s %s %d %d", pos, &side, castle, enpas, &halfMove, &fullMove);
  printf("%d\n", res);
  printf("%s %c %s %s %d %d\n", pos, side, castle, enpas, halfMove, fullMove);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get the following expected result:

```
6
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
```

However when I change the FEN string from a `char` array to a `char` pointer like so

```c
const char *fen = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
```

I get the following result:

```
6
 w KQkq - 0 1
```

as if the first part of the string is ignored. Why is this happening? I'm using GCC 10.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing the point that **C-strings are null-terminated**.

Your declarations

```
char side, pos[128], castle[4], enpas[2];
```

does not leave space for `'\0'` to be appended at the end of those strings after reading them from the FEN.

As a result, it is undefined behaviour.

This will solve the problem:

```
char side, pos[129], castle[5], enpas[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

`castle[4]` isn't enough to store the string "KQkq", there is no space for `\0`, this triggers undefined behavior when `sscanf()` writes `\0` after the end of the array. setting `castle`'s length to *at least* 5 should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is allocating `castle[4]` with only 4 chars. 
And then filling it with "KQkq", a 4 chars string. 
It seems wide enough, but as you can read 
[here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)
at the conversion specifier "s": 
Always stores a null character in addition to the characters matched (so the 
argument array must have room for at least width+1 characters) 

 https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Answer (score 0):

Probably castle will overwrite pos(stack is bottom to top) so, Try this `castle[4]` to `castle[5]` extra one for `NULL` and `enpass[2]` to `enpass`

See this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  char side, pos[128], castle[5], enpas;
  int halfMove, fullMove;

  const char *fen  = "rnbqkbnrpppppppp8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
  const int   res  = sscanf(fen, "%s %c %s %c %d %d", pos, &side, castle, &enpas, &halfMove, &fullMove);

  printf("%d\n", res);
  printf("%s %c %s %c %d %d\n", pos, side, castle, enpas, halfMove, fullMove);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The direction of stack allocation does not regulate how the compiler lays out objects within a stack frame.